# Vue Treeview with lazy load and drag and drop component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, web-component

I lookin for a Vue.js treeview (nested) component which by default support loadOnDemand/lazyLoad nodes and drag and drop? Anyone of you have found any? Been serching for like 4 days now and nothingg suits my needs.. Also it has to work with vuex

Or Element UI lazy load vuex implementation when after updating state in store render new nodes

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#tree